# Do I need to specify data_vars when I import multi-band images with xarray / rasterio

Tags: python, python-xarray, rasterio

I am new to xarray/rioxarray (more familiar with rasterio) so apologies if my question is naïve. I am trying to merge two overlapping datasets (two images with many bands).  They seem to open fine (I can visualize them) but when I try to merge them I get this error:

"AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'data_vars'"

here is my code:

```
path = 'path'
file1 = 'file.dat'
cube1 = xr.open_dataarray(path+file1,engine='rasterio')
file2 = 'file.dat'
cube2 = xr.open_dataarray(path+file2,engine='rasterio')
ds = [
    cube1,
    cube2,
]
merged = merge_datasets(ds)
```

[cube 1 attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v80Yn.png)

Do I need to specify data_vars when I import them? would that be a dictionary of bands?

Comment: do the files have the same dimensions? it would be helpful if you could show what `cube1` and `cube2` look like, and how you'd like them to be joined. do you want them to have the same dimensions, but just different variable names in a Dataset? or do you want them concatenated along a (new or existing) dimension? if you could just post the result of `print(cube1)` and `print(cube2)` as a code block that would be great - SO asks that we not upload images of code/data/errors [for a variety of reasons including accessibility, search, etc](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/).

Comment: also - really helpful if you can show the full traceback, and make sure everything in your code is defined. what's `merge_datasets`?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. I had to update my rioxarray, that was one problem. I think the other problem was I was not being consistent with arrays/datasets.

```
from rioxarray import merge
ds = [
    cube1,
    cube2,
]
merged = merge.merge_arrays(ds)
```